# Simplify $\sum\limits_{r=2}^{p+1} r(r-1)\frac{p!}{(p-r+1)!}\frac1{p^r}$

Tags: probability, summation

If an algorithm samples an integer randomly from $[1, p]$ at each step, and stops if the generated number has occurred before. What is the expected number of steps for this algorithm to stop?

The expression is easy to figure out, which is $$\sum_{r=2}^{p+1} \frac{r(r-1)\ p!}{(p-r+1)!\ p^r}$$ but I have problem in simplifying it. The summation approaches $1.254\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: your formula containes the Gamma-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recapitulating the combinatorics we see that for the algorithm to stop
at  step $q+1$  we must  select  ${p\choose q}$  different values  and
arrange them in one of $q!$  ways for the prefix and combine them with
a singleton  repeat to get  an admissible configuration.  Therefore we
have for the RV $X$ being the number of steps that

$$P[X=q+1] = \frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q} \times q! \times q.$$

As  a  **sanity  check** we  must  verify  that  for  the sum  of  the
probabilities

$$\sum_{q=1}^p P[X=q+1] = 1.$$

We have

$$q! = \sum_{k=1}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^q.$$

and get for the sum

$$\sum_{q=1}^p \frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q} q
\sum_{k=1}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^q
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{q=k}^p 
\frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q} q
{q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^q.$$

Note that

$${p\choose q} {q\choose k} =
\frac{p!}{(p-q)! k! (q-k)!} =
{p\choose k} {p-k\choose q-k}$$

which yields

$$\sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \sum_{q=k}^p 
{p-k\choose q-k}
\frac{1}{p^{q+1}} q (-1)^{q-k} k^q
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \frac{k^k}{p^{k+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{p-k}
{p-k\choose q}
\frac{1}{p^{q}} (q+k) (-1)^{q} k^q.$$

There are two pieces here, the first is

$$\sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k+1}}{p^{k+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{p-k}
{p-k\choose q}
\frac{1}{p^{q}} (-1)^{q} k^q
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k+1}}{p^{k+1}}
\left(1-\frac{k}{p}\right)^{p-k}
= \frac{1}{p^{p+1}}
\sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} k^{k+1} (p-k)^{p-k}$$

and the second is

$$\sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k}}{p^{k+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{p-k}
{p-k\choose q} q
\frac{1}{p^{q}} (-1)^{q} k^q$$

We lower the  upper index to $k=p-1$ because  there is no contribution
due to the  factor ${0\choose 0} \times 0 =  1\times 0.$ Continuing we
have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} {p\choose k} \frac{k^k}{p^{k+1}} (p-k)
\sum_{q=1}^{p-k}
{p-k-1\choose q-1}
\frac{1}{p^{q}} (-1)^{q} k^q
\\ = - \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k+1}}{p^{k+2}} (p-k)
\sum_{q=1}^{p-k}
{p-k-1\choose q-1}
\frac{1}{p^{q-1}} (-1)^{q-1} k^{q-1}
\\ = - \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k+1}}{p^{k+2}} (p-k)
\left(1-\frac{k}{p}\right)^{p-k-1}$$

which would have produced a divide by zero had we not lowered the index.
We thus obtain

$$- \frac{1}{p^{p+1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} {p\choose k} k^{k+1} (p-k)^{p-k}
\\= \frac{1}{p^{p+1}} {p\choose p} p^{p+1} 0^0
- \frac{1}{p^{p+1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^{p} {p\choose k} k^{k+1} (p-k)^{p-k}
\\ = 1 - \frac{1}{p^{p+1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^{p} {p\choose k} k^{k+1} (p-k)^{p-k}.$$

Adding the two contributions we see  that they do indeed sum to one as
required of a probability distribution.

**Asymptotics of expectation.** The expectation is given by

$$\sum_{q=1}^p \frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q} \times q! \times q (q+1)
= 2 \sum_{q=1}^p \frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q} 
\times q! \times \frac{1}{2} q (q+1).$$

We have

$$q! \times \frac{1}{2} q(q+1) = 
\sum_{k=1}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^{q+1}.$$

and get for the sum

$$2\sum_{q=1}^p \frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q}
\sum_{k=1}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^{q+1}
\\ = 2 \sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{q=k}^p 
\frac{1}{p^{q+1}} {p\choose q}
{q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^{q+1}.$$

Re-factor as before to get

$$2 \sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \sum_{q=k}^p 
\frac{1}{p^{q+1}} 
{p-k\choose q-k} (-1)^{q-k} k^{q+1}
\\ = 2 \sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k+1}}{p^{k+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{p-k}
\frac{1}{p^q}
{p-k\choose q} (-1)^{q} k^q
\\ = 2 \sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} \frac{k^{k+1}}{p^{k+1}}
\left(1-\frac{k}{p}\right)^{p-k}
\\ = \frac{2}{p^{p+1}} 
\sum_{k=1}^p {p\choose k} k^{k+1} (p-k)^{p-k}.$$

Observe that when we  multiply two exponential generating functions of
the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that

$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

i.e. the  product of  the two generating  functions is  the generating
function of $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

In the present case  we clearly have

$$A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n+1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = 1 + \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Note that  in the convolution  we get $0^1  = 0$ so $A(z)$  should not
have a constant term while $0^0 = 1$ so $B(z)$ should have one, namely
one.

Recall  the *labeled  tree function*  $T(z)$ from  combinatorics which
counts rooted labeled trees and has the labeled species

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{T})$$

and hence the functional equation

$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

Using either Cayley's formula or Lagrange inversion we have that

$$T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

It follows that

$$ A(z) = z \frac{d}{dz} z \frac{d}{dz} T(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = 1+z \frac{d}{dz} T(z).$$

Note furthermore that

$$\frac{d}{dz} T(z) = \exp T(z) + z \exp T(z) T'(z)$$

so that $$T'(z) = \frac{T(z)/z}{1-T(z)}
\quad\text{and}\quad z T'(z) = \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

Differentiate one more time to get

$$z (z T'(z))' = \frac{z T'(z)}{1-T(z)}
+ \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^2} z T'(z)
\\ = \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^2} + \frac{T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^3}
= \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^3}.$$

This  means that we  have the  following closed  form for  the queried
expectation:

$$\frac{2}{p^{p+1}} \times p! \times [z^p] A(z) B(z)
= \frac{2}{p^{p+1}} \times p! \times 
[z^p] \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^4}.$$

The  dominant  pole here  is  at  $z=1/e$  (we have  $T(1/e)=1$  since
$1=(1/e)\exp(1)$).  The  singular expansion  of $T(z)$ about  $1/e$ is
known and given by

$$T(z) = 1 - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ez} + \frac{2}{3} (1-ez) -\cdots$$

This yields

$$\frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^4} =
T(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^4 \sqrt{1-ez}^4}
\frac{1}{(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{1-ez}+\cdots)^4}$$

Hence the asymptotics originate with

$$\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(1-ez)^2}.$$

Extracting coefficients and back-substituting we thus obtain

$$\frac{2}{p^{p+1}} \times p! 
\times \frac{1}{4} \exp(p) {p+1\choose 1}
\sim \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{p^p} \times p! \times \exp(p).$$

Most of it cancels when we use Stirling's approximation i.e.

$$p! \sim \sqrt{2\pi p} \frac{p^p}{e^p}$$

and we are left with

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\pi p}.}$$

The conjectured constant is 
$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\pi} \approx 1.253314137.$

**Addendum.**  A faster  way to  obtain the  integral is  to  view the
expectation as the convolution of

$$A(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} q(q+1) \times q! \times \frac{z^q}{q!}
= \frac{2z}{(1-z)^3}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^q}{q!} = \exp(z).$$

This yields for the expectation

$$\frac{1}{p} \times p! [z^p] \exp(z) \frac{2z/p}{(1-z/p)^3}.$$

We get the coefficient integral

$$\frac{1}{p^2} \times 
\frac{p!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}}
\exp(z) \frac{2z}{(1-z/p)^3} \; dz.$$

Now put $z=pv$ to get

$$\frac{1}{p^2} \times \frac{p}{p^{p+1}}
\frac{p!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma_2} \frac{1}{v^{p+1}}
\exp(pv) \frac{2pv}{(1-v)^3} \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{p^{p+1}}
\frac{p!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma_2} \frac{1}{v^{p}}
\exp(pv) \frac{2}{(1-v)^3} \; dv.$$

Next put $v/\exp(v) = w$ so that $v=T(w)$ and $dv=T'(w) \; dw$ to get

$$\frac{1}{p^{p+1}}
\frac{p!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma_3} \frac{1}{w^{p}}
\frac{2}{(1-T(w))^3} T'(w) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{p^{p+1}}
\frac{p!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma_3} \frac{1}{w^{p+1}}
\frac{2T(w)}{(1-T(w))^4} \; dw.$$

This is the same as what we obtained earlier.

**Addendum, II.** The proof that

$$q! \times \frac{1}{2} q(q+1) = 
\sum_{k=1}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} k^{q+1}.$$

uses the integral

$$k^{q+1} = 
\frac{(q+1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+2}} \exp(kz) \; dz$$

We get for the sum

$$\frac{(q+1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+2}} 
\sum_{k=1}^q {q\choose k} (-1)^{q-k} 
\exp(kz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{(q+1)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+2}}
\left(-(-1)^q + (\exp(z)-1)^q\right) \; dz.$$

We thus have

$$(q+1)! [z^{q+1}] \left(-(-1)^q + (\exp(z)-1)^q\right)
= (q+1)! [z^{q+1}] (\exp(z)-1)^q
\\ = (q+1)! {q\choose 1} \frac{1}{2}$$

which proves the claim.

**Addendum, III.** The task of verifying that the probabilities sum to
one can also be simplified by using a convolution of

$$A(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} q \times q! \times \frac{z^q}{q!}
= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^q}{q!} = \exp(z).$$

We adapt the computation from the expectation and repeat to obtain the
integral

$$\frac{1}{p^{p+1}}
\frac{p!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma_3} \frac{1}{w^{p+1}}
\frac{T(w)}{(1-T(w))^3} \; dw.$$

Recall that we computed earlier in the process that

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n+1} \frac{z^n}{n!} = z(zT'(z))'
= \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^3}$$ so that this integral is

$$\frac{1}{p^{p+1}} \times p! \times
[w^p] \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n+1} \frac{w^n}{n!}
= \frac{1}{p^{p+1}} p^{p+1} = 1$$

and the probabilities sum to one as claimed.

Consult  *Random Mapping  Statistics* by  Flajolet and  Odlyzko for
background readings.

Comment: Very nice.....!